# Flag based on combination of variables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table A which looks like below-

```
Column1 Column2
0001M   80050
0001M   80053
0001M   80076
0001T   0002T
0001T   34800
0001T   34802
0001T   34804
0001T   36000
0001U   80500
0001U   80502
0001U   81105
0001U   81106

CREATE TABLE mytable(
   Column1 VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  ,Column2 VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO mytable(Column1,Column2) VALUES ('0001M','80050');
INSERT INTO mytable(Column1,Column2) VALUES ('0001M','80053');
INSERT INTO mytable(Column1,Column2) VALUES ('0001M','80076');
INSERT INTO mytable(Column1,Column2) VALUES ('0001T','0002T');
INSERT INTO mytable(Column1,Column2) VALUES ('0001T','34800');
INSERT INTO mytable(Column1,Column2) VALUES ('0001T','34802');
INSERT INTO mytable(Column1,Column2) VALUES ('0001T','34804');
INSERT INTO mytable(Column1,Column2) VALUES ('0001T','36000');
INSERT INTO mytable(Column1,Column2) VALUES ('0001U','80500');
INSERT INTO mytable(Column1,Column2) VALUES ('0001U','80502');
INSERT INTO mytable(Column1,Column2) VALUES ('0001U','81105');
INSERT INTO mytable(Column1,Column2) VALUES ('0001U','81106');
```

I have another table B which has the following columns -

```
ID  SubID
1   0001M
1   80050
1   80053
1   12500
2   0001T
2   0002T
2   34800
2   36000
2   12506
3   80500
3   80502
3   81106

CREATE TABLE mytable(
   ID    INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
  ,SubID VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,SubID) VALUES (1,'0001M');
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,SubID) VALUES (1,'80050');
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,SubID) VALUES (1,'80053');
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,SubID) VALUES (1,'12500');
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,SubID) VALUES (2,'0001T');
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,SubID) VALUES (2,'0002T');
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,SubID) VALUES (2,'34800');
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,SubID) VALUES (2,'36000');
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,SubID) VALUES (2,'12506');
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,SubID) VALUES (3,'80500');
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,SubID) VALUES (3,'80502');
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,SubID) VALUES (3,'81106');
```

Both the values of column1 and column2 of tableA should not occur together in SubID column within each distinct ID column of tableB. If it happens, I need to flag it 1. Otherwise 0. For example, (0001M, 80050) and (0001M, 80053) are not allowed to occur together. Since these two combinations exist in ID=1 of table B, it should be flagged 1.

The output should like this -

```
ID  Flag
1   1
2   1
3   0
```

**Reason Flag = 0 for ID=3** --> Since (80500, 80502) and (80502, 81106) come from column2 only (not from both column 1 and 2), they are allowed to occur together, it is flagged 0. I am using SQL Server 2016 version.

Comment: Careful, that query will be slow if there are many lines with same ID in table B

Comment: on what basis primary key column will allow duplicate values in table ?

Comment: You have `Primary Key` set up incorrectly, you have duplicate values for the same Column1 / Id in each table

Comment: Did you ask this question yesterday too? I'm positive someone did but the question seems to be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also use JOINS to get this done like below.
Logic is that if we get id in tableA from tableB for each column and they are  same then flag should be 1

<kbd>**[see live demo](http://rextester.com/TGTGA47294)**</kbd>

```
select
distinct B.id, flag =case when b1.id = b2.id  then 1 else NULL end
from 
mytableA A 
left join mytableB b1 on b1.subid=a.column1
left join mytableB b2 on b2.subid=a.column2
right join
mytableB B 
on B.id= case when b1.id = b2.id  then b1.id else NULL end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    b1.ID, 
    max(case 
            when exists (select 1 from tableA a where a.Column1=b1.SubId and a.Column2=b2.SubId)
    then 1 else 0 end) as flag
from
    tableB b1
    inner join table B b2 on b1.ID=b2.ID 
group by b1.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . This is tricky.  I think this does what you want.

```
select b.id,
       (case when count(*) > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as flag
from (select distinct b.id from b) b cross join
     a join
     b b1
     on b1.subid = a.column1 and b1.id = b.id join
     b b2
     on b2.subid = a2.column2 and b2.id = b.id
group by b.id;
```